# Google Chrome Flash Player restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, google-chrome

i have a Problem with Google Chrome Version 32. I have implemented two JWPlayer Flash video objects on the site. Now i have implemented a function which allows me to change the DIVs. With this function i am able to change the order of the Players.

In Firefox and Internet Explorer the DIVs changes WITHOUT to restart the Video. In Chrom the DIVs also changes BUT the video reloads on every change.

I have searched in the web but didn´t find any solution.

**Here is my JS code which i use for the switching of the DIVs:**

```
function switchVideo(){ 

//GET Container IDs
var video1  = document.getElementById('video1');
var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');

//Switch Container
var aparent= video1.parentNode;
var asibling= video1.nextSibling===video2? video1 : video1.nextSibling;
video2.parentNode.insertBefore(video1, video2);
aparent.insertBefore(video2, asibling);

//Assing new ID to switched container (not necessary for this question)
video1.id = 'video2';
video2.id = 'video1';

}
```

**This is a example of the DIVs:**

```
<div id='video1'>embedJWPlayer1</div>
<div id='video2'>embedJWPlayer2</div>
```

I hope you guys can give me a hint, how i can prevent the reloading of the video.

Thank you in advance